# Perl chomp convert string into numerical values

Tags: perl

I get a weird behavior for `chomp`. The `<STDIN>` adds trailing newline to the input, and I want to remove it, so I uses chomp like the following:

```
print("Enter Your Name:\n");
$n = <STDIN>;
$n = chomp($n); 
print("Your Name: $n");
$out = "";
for ($i =0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
  $out .= $n;
  print ($out);
  print("\n");
}
```

When I enter any name value (string) such as "Fox" I expect output like:

```
Fox
FoxFox
FoxFoxFox
FoxFoxFoxFox
etc..
```

However, "Fox" is replaced by numerical value `1` i.e

```
1
11
111
1111
```

I tried to get assistance from the official manual of perl about [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) but I could not able to get any help there. Would any one explain why chomp do like that and how could solve this issue?

#### Edit

I reviewed the example on the book again, I found that they use `chomp` witout assign i.e:

```
$n = chomp($n);
# Is replaced by
chomp($n);
```

And Indeed by this way the script printout as expected! Also I don't know how and why?

Comment: The answer is right in the documentation you linked to: "[chomp] returns the total number of characters removed from all its arguments." Therefore, `$n = chomp($n);` sets `$n` to the total number of characters removed by `chomp` (in this case, 1).

Comment: I have an old book about perl from prosofttraining.com they were stated that chomp remove trailing new line from the input of `<STDIN>` @ThisSuitIsBlackNot

Comment: `chomp` *does* remove the trailing newline. It also returns the number of newlines that were stripped. If you do `chomp($n);`, you will strip the trailing newline; if you do `$n = chomp($n);` you will strip the trailing newline, and then assign the return value of `chomp` (i.e. 1) to `$n`.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot So, Perl deals with some subroutines in different way other than other language. i.e changes in variable's value should be assigned to a variable but in this case this subroutine changed it and assigned it automatically, does not it?

Comment: Perl always [passes by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value). This means that subroutines can alter their parameters. See [`perldoc perlsub`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) and [Perl call-by-reference or call-by-value?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5741042/176646) for details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the perldoc on chomp:

> It returns the total number of characters removed from all its arguments

You're setting $n to the return value of chomp($n):

> $n = chomp($n);

To do what you want, you can simply
`chomp($n)`

Comment: Or even `chomp( $n = <STDIN> );`

Comment: well, this answer is already written in [ThisSuitIsBlackNot](http://stackoverflow.com/users/176646/thissuitisblacknot)'s comment.